# Support of multiple reply-to in Sendgrid Java library

Tags: java, email, sendgrid

I am using sendgrid-java library which internally uses V3 API to send emails. In Sendgrid's API documentation([link](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/mail-send/mail-send#multiple-reply-to-emails)), it is mentioned that support for `reply_to_header` has been added. But that has not been handled in the Java library yet. When can we expect that support to get added in sendgrid-java library?

I tried using V3 API to check the support for multiple reply-to emails and it was working fine.
[image]

[image]

But in the latest version of [Mail.html](https://javadoc.io/static/com.sendgrid/sendgrid-java/4.9.3/com/sendgrid/helpers/mail/Mail.html) of java library, `replyToList` field is not there.

Comment: I have raised a pull request as well to handle this issue. https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-java/pull/737

Comment: I don't believe this to be a useful question for SO, as it does not include an actual problem which can be solved by the community. As you already have made a pull request, you need to wait for it to be approved. Until then you can always build your own version which already includes your pull request

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this seems to be a support request, which should be addressed to Sendgrid, not to the Stack Overflow community.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I reached out to Sendgrid's support team first. They only asked me to post the request on SO. As per them, best course of action to have anything added in library is to reach out for assistance on Stack Overflow community. Please suggest if this question still needs to be closed. I have anyways created my own version of Mail.java and using that in my application.

Comment: Well, then Sendgrid is wrong, because Stack Overflow is not intended for that. And if **you** post on Stack Overflow, you are expected to follow the expectation layed out in the help center and ask a question that can be answered by the **community**. What you're asking right now can only be answered by Sendgrid, and would basically be soliciting opinions on what we think Sendgrid will do and when.